# Spark Job Wrapping a Transformation With Local Operations (Very Slow and OOM Problems)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a Spark job that analyzes a time series in a variety of ways. Through a series of transformations, I take a dataframe and drop to rdds, so that I have rows structured as:

`Row[((tuple, key) t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, ...)]`

Let's call this rdd: `rdd`.

I call `rdd.flatMap(foo(r[1:]))`, and I expected `foo` to take as it's input a list of times, and deliver a list of analytics as it's output.

Let's say

```
def foo(times):
    return [average(times), percentile(times, 25)]
```

When I run this job, it takes forever and I get `OOM` errors that cause everything to fail. `times` should have no more than `600K` items, and that's the super outlier case. Most would likely have between `10K` - `100K`.

I can't use `reduceByKey()` because the operations I need to perform require looking at the entire time series and going back and forth multiple times.

Does anyone have any recommendations on a way to solve this `OOM` slowness problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've read your question correctly, you have an RDD where each row is a list of tuples and some rows can have up to 600K tuples.

Without knowing your cluster configurations or looking at the actual code, I can only speculate. My best guess is that since Spark only partitions by row, rows with huge numbers of columns can't have their columns distributed among partitions, which is causing your out of memory errors.

If that's the cause, you may need to increase your cluster capacity or restructure your data so that each tuple is on its own row.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. One row, which looks like `Row[(tuple, key) t1, t2, t3, ...]` may have `600K` `t's`, meaning `600K` elements stored in the tuple value of the `key,value` pair.

Comment: So, rows have a tuple as the key, and then the value is a list of up to 600K elements? I think my point about too many columns still stands.

Comment: I ended up tweaking the structure and it worked out.